# JSON field for model Django 3.0a

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, django-jsonfield, django-3.0

I'm using Django 3.0a with Python 3.7

I had searched a lot for a JSON field that works with the Data base sqlite and other (I know that Django > 2.2 support JSONfield for postgres)

Now I had tried this libraries:

1. https://github.com/adamchainz/django-jsonfield
2. https://github.com/dmkoch/django-jsonfield
3. https://github.com/rpkilby/jsonfield2/

All of them throw very similar error:

```
from django.utils import six
ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils' (C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-3.0a1-py3.7.e
gg\django\utils\__init__.py)
```

I searched the issue and i found that the "six" library which is missing suppose to deal with differences between Python 2 and 3.

How can I fix it or do you know another way around to use JSON fields in the Django model?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is there any special reason you are using an alpha version?

Comment: No, actually this is my first project and i have just downloaded the latest with pip

Comment: Try the latest released version of Django 2.2.

Comment: Tried that now I'm working on Django 2.2.6 and it works fine! Another problem is that I can't use it in my template...

Comment: this is how I tried to implement in the template: <td>{{ result.search_inputs|txtmegusha }}</td> The "txtmegusha" is the key of the dictionary

Comment: Please open a new question for the new problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import jsonfield
from django.db import models

class Modelname(models.Model):
    data=jsonfield.JSONField()
```

Data column saves the json data in Sqlite database.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with

- `Djongo` - Extension to the traditional `Django ORM framework`.
- `Djongo`'s  `EmbeddedField` Class (`EmbeddedField` is similar to `JSONField`).

I give you the documentation:

https://www.djongomapper.com/using-django-with-mongodb-data-fields/